# Collapse other list Android

Tags: android

```
 list.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
                LinearLayout linear = (LinearLayout) view.findViewById(R.id.linear);

                if (linear.getVisibility() == View.GONE) {
                    linear.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                } else {
                    linear.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                }

            }
        });
```

When I click On listitem it expands. but when i click on the next item the previous one does bot collapse. I want to expand only one at a time without using expandablelistview.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
private int lastExpandedPosition = -1;
private ExpandableListView lv; //your expandable listview

lv.setOnGroupExpandListener(new OnGroupExpandListener() {
    @Override
    public void onGroupExpand(int groupPosition) {
            if (lastExpandedPosition != -1
                    && groupPosition != lastExpandedPosition) {
                lv.collapseGroup(lastExpandedPosition);
            }
            lastExpandedPosition = groupPosition;
    }
});
```

Comment: I dont want to use expandable listview buddy.

Comment: So, you should save lastExpandedPosition and set linear.setVisibility(View.GONE); for last position by hand.

Comment: can you please elaborate? i am new